# Get free/used ports in a specific range

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, terminal, port

Is it possible to get either the free or used ports between a specific range? If yes, whats is the command?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Do you mean something like ss -tulpn | cut -d ":" -f 2 | cut -f 1 -d " | egrep [100-200]?

Comment: Your `egrep` regular expression is wrong. `[100-200]` matches a single character from the set `0,1,2`. Try before you post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `man lsof`.

```
sudo lsof -iTCP:20-26
```

Will show in-use ports.